# How to get a string from a dynamic web page that is refreshed by scrolling down

Tags: c#, webclient, downloadstring

I want to get a string from a dynamic web page that is refreshed by scrolling down. This is not working:

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
string data = web.DownloadString("https://www.radiojavan.com/mp3s/browse/featured/all");
```

Comment: It's called Lazy Loading scraping, I'm not sure that it is that easy in c#. Try looking into Python here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/167327/scraping-the-full-content-from-a-lazy-loading-webpage

Comment: This is also called a lazy question, what research have you done, what have you tried, pasting 1 sentence and 2 lines of code is a low quality question

Comment: And just to help you out in the future, Jon Skeet has made it easy for you https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: The problem is that that dynamic loading is triggered by DOM operations (scrolling) in combination with javascript, things you don't have with a simple web request.

Answer (score 0):

Load the partials of the pages:

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
var data = string.Empty;

for(var page = 1; page < 10; page++){
  var url = $"https://www.radiojavan.com/mp3s/content?type=featured&query=all&page={page}"

  data += web.DownloadString("https://www.radiojavan.com/mp3s/browse/featured/all");

}
```